# Special character conversion issue in Datastage

Tags: oracle, special-characters, netezza, nls, datastage

In Datastage, we have source system as Oracle and target system as Netezza. In Oracle the column datatype is varchar whereas in Netezza it is nvarchar. Most of the characters are Latin and Dutch.
We are getting character in our table row which is exactly opposite to the one mentioned in bracket (`) means it's heading towards right and slanting on left(mostly dutch). We feel it is Dutch character which represent apostrophe. The table consists of million records and many values in table have this special character. We want to process the value as it is but we are getting garbage value. Can anyone help us in which conversion function we should try?

I tried iso-8859-1 and iso-8859-15

Comment: If someone can help asap that would be helpful. it's bit urgent.

Comment: Have you tried loading the Oracle Data as NVarchar? What are the Character Sets used in both the Oracle and the Netezza databases? (something like AL32UTF8) Sometimes, importing the table definitions via `Import/Table Definitions/Start Connector Import Wizard` in the DataStage Designer can help to get the correct datatypes. (although I've seen that failing, too. it's worth a try)

Comment: @JustusKenklies   Thank you for your reply.Yes character set is al32utf8. I tried loading as nvarchar ,did not work. I came to know they are acute accent x00B4 character. Is there way to handle them in datastage

Comment: Encoding is always a beast. I just can recommend to dive deep and collect as much information about your databases character and language settings and try to handle everything as unicode (NVarChar is always Unicode) and try avoiding having too much conversion points. In DS, you can also use Char/Varchar with the extended unicode flag and play around with that and there are also unicode conversion functions for the transformer, but I must say I try to avoid that.

To investigate where the information gets lost, add copy stages inbetween the stages, attach peek stages and watch what they log.